# How to post a message to Slack via user token and Slack API

Tags: api, slack, slack-api

Is it possible to send a message via Slack API from my current user? I've created a slack user token, documentation also said:

```
User tokens represent the same access a user has to a workspace -- the channels, conversations, users, reactions, etc. they can see
Write actions with user tokens are performed as if by the user themselves
```

but when I'm trying to send some requests via Slack API, I get notified that I have no ops for it, example:

-> GET https://slack.com/api/users.identity (+ bearer with my user token)

->

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "missing_scope",
    "needed": "identity.basic",
    "provided": "identify,app_configurations:read,app_configurations:write"
}
```

Same when I'm trying to send a message / get a conversations list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is to send a message then make sure to add the `chat:write` scope to your app from your OAuth & Permissions page on your app's management site. Remove all the other scopes, save an re-install your app. You should then be able to send a message using the chat.postMessage method. If you want to use the `conversations.list` method then you'll need to add the channels:read scope. To use the `users.identity` method you will need to enable Sign In with Slack as outlined [here](https://api.slack.com/authentication/sign-in-with-slack).